# Java - How to use global variable inbetween multiple source folders?

Tags: java, global-variables

I created seperate source folder for each module, say **mod1** & **mod2** and the **src** source folder as common for each source folder.
I want to access a global variable in **mod1** & **mod2** from the **src**.
Attaching the folder structure

[image]

Calculation.java

```
package common;

import org.openqa.selenium.WebDriver;

public class Calculation {
    public static WebDriver driver;
    public static boolean bResult;
    public static String excelName;

    public  Calculation(WebDriver driver){
        Calculation.driver = driver;
        Calculation.bResult = true;
        Calculation.excelName = "testdata.xlsx";
    }
}
```

How to access **excelName** in **Registration.java** ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First you need to move excelName to a Constants class. and then you can use it like as below.

```
public class Constants {

public static final String excelName  = "samle.xls"

}
```

in Registration.java use it like..

```
Constants.excelName
```

Comment: wow it worked..i also want to make **dataprovider** as a common and put in **src**. Can I ask this question here or put it as a new question

Comment: ask a new question.